Translations in a typescript object are not working
I have a bug that I don't understand, I am using lingui for i18n of my app. I have translations done with the macro t in a typescript object: https://github.com/Flaburgan/disco2very/blob/master/data/ademe/footprintDetailCategories.ts#L8
They are correctly extracted: https://github.com/Flaburgan/disco2very/blob/master/locales/en/messages.po#L164
And correctly compiled, I find them with the good key in both my English and French ts file which result from the compilation.
The array is then used here: https://github.com/Flaburgan/disco2very/blob/master/components/explanation-dialog.tsx#L48
However, after deploying in production, translations are not displayed, the key is displayed instead, for both English and French:

Here is how I load i18n: https://github.com/Flaburgan/disco2very/blob/master/components/App.tsx#L28
What am I doing wrong? Is it that the array is not "aware" of the local to load? Thank you.

Some of your links are broken. You must have updated your master branch since your post. I recommend checking your code to a dedicated branch for asking questions and leaving them be until your question is resolved.
If you have a big object with translation needs, I recommend msg macro instead of t. The syntax is very similar. You then use i18n._(SOME_MESSAGE_DESCRIPTER) to access the localized strings.
